# IllegalArgumentException from Activity#startActivity(Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent

The [Android#startActivity(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) is specified to throw `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` if there was no Activity found to run the given Intent.

I therefore have code like

```
try {
    // Try to start activity provided by external app:
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // [...] Inform user about external app needed
    // for this functionality to work.
}
```

which catches `ActivityNotFoundException` to handle the case where the external app is not installed.

However, from the Crashes & ANRs section of the Google Play Developer Console I'm starting to get crashes as `IllegalArgumentException: Unknown component com.example.package/com.example.package.Activity`. Should code invoking `startActivity()` be ready to handle that exception as well? Is this a framework bug (or documentation error)?

Comment: have you defined this activity in manifest ?

Comment: No, the activity is defined in an external app (which may or may not be installed).

Answer (score 0):

This exception generally arises when you haven't declared it in your manifest file. So, try doing it
Somewhere inside your application tag do this

```
 <activity
            android:name="Your_Activity_Name"
            android:theme="Whatever your theme is"
          </activity>
```

If its any other issue please let me know.

Comment: The activity is defined by an external app, which may or may not be installed by the user. I'm trying to catch `ActivityNotFoundException` to handle the case when the app is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check it. This is the better approach then handling exception

```
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (list.size() > 0)
{
 // start your activity
}
```